# Issue with Gifted Chat, InputToolbar position for Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I would like to know how to fix correctly the position of the InputToolbar when the keyboard is visible.

If I add a marginBottom, the textInput position change. And if I change the position of textInput, the position of InputToolbar change and when the keyboard closes and open again every marginbottom are ignored.

[image: Position keyboard visible without margin]

[image: Position keyboard visible with InputToolbar margin]

[image: Position keyboard visible with textInput margin]

On an iOS device everything is fine, the issue is only for Android.

```
  <View style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor, flex: 1}}>
      <GiftedChat
        messages={messages}
        onSend={handleSend}
        renderSend={renderSend}
        user={mapUser(auth.currentUser)}
        loadEarlier={loadEarlier}
        isLoadingEarlier={isLoadingEarlier}
        isTyping={typing != null} 
        onLoadEarlier={handleLoadEarlier}
        onInputTextChanged={handleInputTextChanged}
        renderBubble={renderBubble}
        bottomOffset={-10}
        listViewProps={{
          keyboardDismissMode: "on-drag"
          }}
        style={{backgroundColor: backgroundColor}}
        renderFooter={renderFooter}
        list
        renderInputToolbar={(props) => (
          <InputToolbar
            {...props}
            containerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: '#F4F4F4',
              marginLeft: 15,
              marginRight: 15,
              marginBottom: isKeyboardVisible ? (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0 : 35) : (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 10 : 35),
              borderColor: 'grey',
              height:44,
              borderRadius: 25
            }}
            textInputStyle={{
              color: '#333333',
              marginBottom: isKeyboardVisible ? (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0 : 40) : 40,
              fontSize: 14,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto-medium',
            }}
            placeholder="Votre message ..."
          />
        )}
        renderChatFooter={() => (
          <View style={{marginVertical: isKeyboardVisible ? (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0 : 0) : (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 5 : 20)}}/> // 20
        )}
      />
    </View>
```

I tried to add some marginBottom values

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your code:

```
import { Platform, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

{ Platform.OS === 'android' ? < KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="height" /> : null }

{ Platform.OS === 'iOS' ? < KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="height" /> : null }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It was because of Expo, I just removed "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode" in app.json and it fixed the issue

[image: screen]

Comment: More details here -> https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/2430